# Clustering Spring Boot applications

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have an adapter (written in Spring Boot and Spring Integration) retrieving currency reates from two different sources (via REST and proprietary library). I filter unnecesary things, create instances of class known in my system and send rates to JMS cluster. I want this adapter to be replicated. Only one instance should be running at the same time. When one crashes (I know it from health endpoint) another one should start publishing rates. How can I achieve such effect? I know that available services can be registered using Eureka but how to turn one of them on automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is using spring-cloud-cluster. One can use either zookeeper or hazelcast to negotiate leadership. From few instances only one is given a leader role. If it crashes, another one takes its role (it is informed via event propagation). You can also use yieldLeadership method to manually relinquish leadership (if health indicator says something is wrong with the application).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details it is hard to give you a recommendation.

I'd personally say Eureka is not build for what you are trying to achieve. But it sounds more like you want to have a look into ZooKeeper. Also see [Eureka FAQ](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/FAQ#why-not-use-curatorzookeeper-as-a-service-registry) for reference. ZooKeeper was exactly build for doing what you are trying to achieve: [leader election](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/recipes.html#sc_leaderElection).

On the other hand, if you can survive also with having the service down for a few seconds I'd suggest you use either your script that monitors the `/health` endpoint already to restart the service or use systems who already have this build in like *Systemd* or *Docker*, where you can define Restart policies.